# How can I get the SUM of SQL data in single row for multiple dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Big Query to get the sum of Google Search Console (GSC) data over a week period, and joining other GSC tables. But I need to join on the date since the tables hold different URL paths. How can I get the output of this data to show the sum of the date **range** instead of the sum of each day?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE(_partitiontime)AS date,
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, "path.*zip") THEN "path_ zip"
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, "path.*landmark") THEN "path_landmark" 
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, "path.*services") THEN "path_services"
    ELSE 'other'
  END
    AS path_categories,
    SUM(clicks)AS path_clicks,
    SUM(impressions)AS path_impressions,
    AVG(rank)AS path_avg_rank,
    COUNT(query)AS path_mc_kwds
  FROM
    `path_gsc_table`
  WHERE
    _partitiontime BETWEEN "2021-01-24" AND  "2021-01-30"
  GROUP BY
    path_categories, date ) AS gsc_path
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
    DATE(_partitiontime)AS date,
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, "url.*zip") THEN "url_ zip"
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, "url.*landmark") THEN "url_landmark" 
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, "url.*services") THEN "url_services"
    ELSE 'other'
  END
    AS url_categories,
    SUM(clicks)AS url_clicks,
    SUM(impressions)AS url_impressions,
    AVG(rank)AS url_avg_rank,
    COUNT(query)AS num_url_kwds
  FROM
    `gsc_url_table`
  WHERE
    _partitiontime BETWEEN "2021-01-24" AND  "2021-01-30"
  GROUP BY
   url_categories, date ) AS gsc_url
ON
  gsc_path.date = gsc_url.date
```

Desired output (as opposed to each of the 7 days in its own row)
[image]

Comment: Remove `date` from the `group by`.

Comment: It throws an error, says it's neither grouped nor aggregated. I need to select the date to join the two tables "ON" date (I think).

Comment: . . And remove it from the `SELECT` as well.

Comment: ... and JOIN "ON gsc_minute_clinic = gsc_shop"? Results look good I think. Thanks!